# InternetShortcut object IPersistFile::Save fails with E_FAIL (0x80004005)

Tags: windows, winapi, com

This one had me stuck for too long, so I'm self answering this. Apologies for the sardonic tone!

Trying to use the official API to create .url files has only [the following documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/internet-shortcuts#creating-an-internet-shortcut-from-a-url):

> - Create an instance of the Internet shortcut object with CoCreateInstance, using a CLSID of CLSID_InternetShortcut.
> - Use the IUniformResourceLocator::SetURL method to set the URL in the shortcut.
> - Use the IPersistFile::Save method to save the shortcut file to a desired location.

Ok, so that should look something like this (my actual code is rust, sorry for the lack of testing):

```cpp
CoInitializeEx(nullptr, 0);

IUniformResourceLocator* url = nullptr;
CoCreateInstance(
  CLSID_InternetShortcut,
  nullptr,
  CLSCTX_INPROC,
  IID_IUniformResourceLocator,
  (void**)&url,
);
```

Oh this fails with E_NOINTERFACE? Well there's not much code yet, so it's not too hard to guess that you have to init with STA, instead of the default MTA:

```cpp
CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
```

So that's the first step, the second is just something like:

```cpp
url->SetURL(L"https://stackoverflow.com", 0);
```

Now for the third step:

```cpp
IPersistFile* file = nullptr;
url->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&file);
file->Save(L"best-site.url", FALSE);
```

Huh, `Save()` is returning E_FAIL? That's strange, I'm using exactly the same code for saving a ShellLink object to a .lnk file?

Comment: "*it's not too hard to guess that you have to init with STA, instead of the default MTA*" - sounds like a job for Raymond Chen to write a blog explaining why `IUniformResourceLocator` doesn't work in the MTA ;-)  Though, [this port](https://narkive.com/RmouzGU2.2) sums it up: "*My guess would be, InternetShortcut is marked as an Apartment-threaded object, and IUniformResourceLocator interface is not marshallable.*"

Comment: And my guess for why it is marked as apartment-threaded is that IURL has an invoke method that has an HWND parameter, and thus presumably sometimes shows UI (browser selection?). This makes it pretty annoying if you just want to set the URL, perhaps you can instead get the `IPropertySetStore` in MTA? Worth testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple: `InternetShortcut` for whatever reason, unlike `ShellLink` and presumably other shell objects requires that the path for `Save()` is absolute. (And only `Save()`, `Load()` is quite happy with a relative path)

So, the full working code using [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil):

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <IntShCut.h>
#include <wil/com.h>

void save_link(LPCWSTR url_value, LPCWSTR path) {
    auto url = wil::CoCreateInstance<IUniformResourceLocator>(CLSID_InternetShortcut, CLSCTX_INPROC);
    THROW_IF_FAILED(url->SetURL(url_value, 0));
    auto file = url.query<IPersistFile>();
    WCHAR full_path[MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathName(path, ARRAYSIZE(full_path), full_path, nullptr);
    THROW_IF_FAILED(file->Save(full_path, FALSE));
}

int main() {
    THROW_IF_FAILED(CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED));
    save_link(L"https://stackoverflow.com", L"best-site.url");
}
```

Comment: To be fair, the docs for `IPersistFile::Save` do state that the provided path should be absolute. `IShellLink` is the weirdo for accepting it.